# Redux toolkit + Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Hello everyone I has a problem,

this is codeSilce.ts file

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const codeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "codeApply",
  initialState: {
    codeOTP: "",
    token: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    addcode: (state, action) => {
      state.codeOTP = action.payload;
    },
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { addcode, setToken } = codeSlice.actions;

export default codeSlice.reducer;
```

this is reducer file

```
import codeSlice from 'app/slices/codeSlice';

const rootReducer = {
    code: codeSlice
};

export type reducer = typeof rootReducer;

export default rootReducer;
```

this is store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";


const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
```

I use this in my file but it has some bug

```
import { reducer } from 'app/reducers'
const codeState = useSelector((state: reducer) => state.code)

const code = codeState.codeOTP; // wrong here
const token = codeState.token; // and here
```

this bug is

```
Property 'codeOTP' does not exist on type 'Reducer<{ codeOTP: string; token: string; }, AnyAction>'.
```

I don't know why this happening, I have console.log(codeState) but it is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues come from a misunderstanding here.

```
const rootReducer = {
    code: codeSlice
};

export type reducer = typeof rootReducer;
```

`{code: codeSlice}` is a reducer map object.  It is an object that maps the properties of the state to their individual reducers.  It is **not** a reducer.  A reducer is a `function`.

Everything is fine on the javascript side of things because `configureStore` [can accept](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#parameters) this `ReducersMapObject` for the `reducer` property.  But you have issues with basing your typescript types off of it.

Redux-toolkit exports some helpful utility types that you can use.  Note that the type that you want in your `useSelector` is the type of the *state*, not the *reducer*.

```
import codeSlice from 'app/slices/codeSlice';
import { StateFromReducersMapObject } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// a reducer map object
const rootReducer = {
    code: codeSlice
};

// the state for this reducer map
export type State = StateFromReducersMapObject<typeof rootReducer>;

export default rootReducer;
```

This type `State` evaluates to:

```
type State = {
    code: {
        codeOTP: string;
        token: string;
    };
}
```